Dynamic passing parmeters to a function
I want to automate the data classification in Snowflake.
So, first I created a list of tables along with their schemas and databases:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "MY_CLASSIFICATION"."PUBLIC"."ALL_DATABASES_TABLE_LIST"
AS (

select table_schema, 
       table_name, 
       created as create_date,
       last_altered as modify_date,
       'SNOWFLAKE' as database_name
from "SNOWFLAKE".information_schema.tables 
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

UNION ALL
select table_schema,
       table_name,
       created as create_date,
       last_altered as modify_date,
       'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' as database_name
from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA".information_schema.tables 
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by table_schema,
        table_name 
);

Then I want to run the EXTRACT_SEMANTIC_CATEGORIES function to classify data by dynamically passing fully qualified name of the table, passing one record at a time from the table I've created above.
Like this:
select extract_semantic_categories('"SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."CUSTOMER"'); 

Then I also need to pass dynamically the same to the stored procedure:
call associate_semantic_category_tags
('"SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."CUSTOMER"' , (select * from MY_CLASSIFICATION."PUBLIC"."ALL_DATABASES_TABLE_LIST") ); 

Ho do i do it?
Thanks in advance for any help.
